# using Integer objects in Java API

Tags: java

I was reviewing a coworker's code, and noticed that he was using `Integer` objects instead of `int`s in some APIs (getters, setters, instance variables, and method parameters). When I asked him why, he told me it was because he wanted to use `null` to indicate an uninitialized state, because there was no good default value.

I feel conflicted. On one hand, this is a common practice with other objects (I know, Java 8 makes it better with `Optional<T>`). On the other hand, it seems that the chance of a `NullPointerException` is higher if API clients use autoboxing.

Is this a good coding practice?

Answer (score 4):

This is completely reliant on the problem domain and how the interface is used. I have written interfaces both ways.

I have seen SOAP libraries not allow null values, making `Integer` completely unnecessary.

On the flip side, I have used `Integer` for cached data (you specifically mention "instance variables" in your question, not just the API):

```
public class Test implements Serializable {

  private transient Integer hash;

  public int hashCode() {
    if (hash == null) {
      hash = <time-consuming hash operation>;
    }
    return hash.intValue();
  }
}
```

In this case, the object is being used as a key in a `HashMap` so it makes sense to cache a hash value rather than recompute it over and over. Using `Integer` means I can say with 100% certainty that I have already computed the value or not (as opposed to `String`'s sentinel value which in theory can produce a hash collision).

If an API accepts Integer but assumes not null, that is a *fail-fast* scenario. It will throw a `NullPointerException` and should do so quickly. Client code using your API should encounter this exception rather quickly, making it easy to find and fix the bad data when testing.

I recommend using `Integer` (maybe with [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) to make it clear) for optional data, and `int` when it is required.

Comment: I agree with your answer but I don't understand the reference to `String`'s sentinel value. What is that about?

Comment: @5gon12eder `String` uses a value of 0 to indicate there is no hash. It is possible for a string to hash to 0, so it would rehash each time.

Comment: Is this an implementation detail you've found out (for some implementation) or is it somehow required? I cannot find anything related to this [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode--).

Comment: @5gon12eder implementation detail. Look at `String.java`.

Answer (score 2):

Any value which can ever be `null` is a `NullPointerException` waiting to happen. Any code which checks those values need to do an additionally check for `null`, which is easy to forget for you and even easier to forget for any other users of your classes.

For that reason whenever I have a value which can be intentionally unknown or absent, I use [`Optional<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) since Java 8.

Note that using `optional.get()` returns `NoSuchElementException` on absent values which is only slightly more useful than a `NullPointerException`. Instead I prefer the pattern `optional.ifPresent( [lambda-expression] );`

An alternative solution to avoid `NullPointerException`s is the [Null Object Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern). When you have an own class which can be null, also add a singleton which extends that class and represents an uninitialized or unknown instance of that class and which implements all public methods to behave gracefully.